# Android Studio не видит девайс

Tags: android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, начал заниматься разработкой под Android. Решил для отладки использовать свой девайс Meizu m2 mini. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что Android Studio не видит моё устройство при подключении. Искал много способов исправить данную проблему
 1) Зайти в настройки > для разработчиков > Режим отладки;
 2) Устанавливал pdaNet на компьютер и на устройство. Отображалось в диспетчере устройств как Android phones, но, пытаясь использовать команду с cmd adb devices не отображалось соединение, и, следовательно, Andoid Studio не отображало соединение.
 3) Также устанавливал Google USB в SKD manager, но также не помогло.
 4) Пробовал скачивать драйверы adb для своего смартфона, но при попытке обновить драйверы через диспетчер устройств и при выборе скаченной папки с драйверами отображалось сообщение вида "Извините, но никаких драйверов не обнаружено". 
Также на официальном сайте https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver нет устройств компании Meizu, что меня насторожило.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему. Спасибо

Решил проблему, сменил режим подключения к компьютеру на "Подключен как камера (PTP)"

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/205572/